# How do I define table relationships in phpmyadmin 3.3.7?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I don't see the "relations view" that used to exist. Any suggestions? I'd rather not have to drop all of my tables in order to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. When creating a new database, the default database `type` is set to "MyISAM". Change that to "InnoDB" and save. Now the "relations view" link will be available next to the "print view" on the table's structure page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a database table for PHPMyAdmin?

The feature should still be there, check the relations configuration options (see http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/)